# jquery ui selecmenu add element

Tags: jquery-ui

Im trying the jquery ui selecmenu, described here:
http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu

I'm using verion 1.4.2 of jQuery.

Im rendering select boxes as described in the demos.

My question is: how do I add en element to a select box after it is rendered? When I run my code and ad an option element to the select, it adds a new one to the select box... but it doesnt show on the page, i.e the surrounding markup is not added.

How can I make the change appear on the page?

Here's some code:

head section:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui.selectmenu.js"></script>
 ....

<select class="custom" id="subcatselect" name="subcategory">
    <option value=''>header</option>
    <option value="yy">yy</option>
    <option value="xx">xx</option>
 </select>

 <a href="#" id="foo">add element</a>
```

My document ready handler:

```
$("#foo").click(function(){
   $('#subcatselect').addNode('FOO','BAR');       
});
```

The addNode function is loaded from another file:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.addNode = function(text, value) {
return this.each(function(){
  if (this.tagName=='SELECT') {
    var selectElement = this;

var option = new Option(text, value);
      if ($.browser.msie) {
        selectElement.add(option);
      }
      else {
        selectElement.add(option,null);
      }

  }
});
}
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see a solution in this thread, by Lorenzo..
[select next option in jquery selectmenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193765/select-next-option-in-jquery-selectmenu)

i.e this type of code:

```
$("#myselect").selectmenu('disable'); 
$('#mycatselect').html('');
$('#mycatselect').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", "foo").text('bar'));
$("#myselect").selectmenu('destroy').selectmenu();
```

Comment: Thats just a mess. Not an solution. Please do not use this.

Answer (score 3):

Its not possible to use the above linked version of selectmenu with jQuery 1.4.x

The version linked in OP is not officialy released yet and works with the latest master (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/selectmenu) of jQuery UI. Its possible latest versions of the plugin wont work with 1.10.x too.

If you want to use selectmenu with an older release of jQuery / UI please use the legacy version in my private GitHub repo: https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/tree/selectmenu

If you provide a demo fiddle I will take a look and add some working code.

Hint: just add the option to the original element and...

- call refresh method (for new version)
- call selectmenu() again (for
  legacy version)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem, but the solution didn't seem very elegant so I read the selectmenu wiki located on github (https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu).

The wiki states:

**Add / delete / modify options**

It's possible to rename an option or even add one to the selectmenu. Simply change the original select element and apply selectmenu() to it:

```
$('select').selectmenu();
```

I tried this in my code and it worked correctly.

Comment: The mentioned wiki is not for the used version of selectmenu.

Answer (score 0):

Why using the plugin?

You can simply achieve the same thing:

```
$("#foo").click(function(){
   $('#subcatselect').append("<option value='foo'>bar</option");       
});
```

Comment: Thanks but that part is not the problem...  The problem is to update the ui list...